# Why do I get syntax error but in same cmd if I remove else block it does not give syntax error?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
M_ID,M_NAME,DEPT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,Salary 
M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000 
M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000 
M003,AJIT,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,70000 
M004,SHARVARI,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000 
M005,ADITYA,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000 
M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000 
M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000 
M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000 
M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000 
M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
```

```
awk -F\, -v sum=0 -v sum1=0 '{if($3=="D003"){sum=sum+$6} elseif ($3=="D004") {sum1=sum1+$6}} END{print sum,sum1}' Joining_date.txt
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `elseif` in `awk`, you need to use `else if`:

```
$ awk -F, -v sum=0 -v sum1=0 '{if($3=="D003"){sum=sum+$6} else if ($3=="D004") {sum1=sum1+$6}} END{print sum,sum1}' file
140000 250000
```

Or, a bit more legible:

```
awk -F, -v sum=0 -v sum1=0 '{
    if($3=="D003"){
        sum=sum+$6
    } 
    else if ($3=="D004") {
        sum1=sum1+$6
    }
} END{
    print sum,sum1
}' file
```

Comment: yes..i could work with this modification.. beauty part looks good too  but I'm new to Linux so still not used to writing this..anyway..very huge thanks

Comment: You're welcome, @Faisal. And don't worry, we were all new once! By the way, if this or any other answer you receive solves your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.